# Trying to uninstall and reinstall Pytorch on Mac and I can't get anywhere with it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm on an M1 Mac, so no cuda support. My python version is 3.9.12

When I run

```
conda uninstall pytorch
pip uninstall torch
pip uninstall torch
```

I get

```
(base) user@User-MacBook-Pro stuff % sh test2
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - pytorch


WARNING: Skipping torch as it is not installed.
WARNING: Skipping torch as it is not installed.
```

However, when I run

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(5,3)
print(x)
```

I get

```
(base) user@User-MacBook-Pro stuff % python3 test
tensor([[0.1614, 0.3981, 0.5020],
        [0.7478, 0.8795, 0.9549],
        [0.9258, 0.9658, 0.9050],
        [0.5181, 0.2635, 0.7052],
        [0.8233, 0.1299, 0.1988]])
```

Indicating that Pytorch is still somehow installed.

I have no idea on how to proceed.

When I run

```
print(torch.__file__)
```

I get

```
(base) user@User-MacBook-Pro speechbrain % python3 test3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3", line 1, in <module>
    print(torch.__file__)
NameError: name 'torch' is not defined
```

So I have no idea where Pytorch is located.

Comment: When you begin using conda, you already have a default environment named `base`. You don't want to put programs into your base environment, though. Create separate environments to keep your programs isolated from each other ([source](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-environments)). Then, in case of such problems you can just recreate a new env.

Comment: As alex wrote, it is not wise to run everything in base, you can use: 'conda create --name pytorch' to create a new conda env. for pytorch. Make sure it is activated before you try to use it. Btw PyTorch supports the M1 gpu natively now: https://pytorch.org/blog/introducing-accelerated-pytorch-training-on-mac/, so no need for cuda